# InvalidUseOfMatchersException for Rest Client Junit in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write Junit test case using mockito for Rest Client in Spring Boot. Getting the error while mocking the response as shown below:

## Mocking Response using Mockito:

```
   UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(Url);

        Mockito.when(this.restTlsTemplate
                .exchange(Mockito.eq(builder.toString()), HttpMethod.GET, Mockito.any(), RestResponse.class)
                .getBody()).thenReturn(response());
```

## Error getting for above mocking response:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at (ApplicationTests.java:54)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Can anyone please check this and help me on this.

Comment: The error it pretty clear - you’re mixing up Mockito marchers with literal values. You must use matchers for all values or no values - you cannot combine matchers and literals. In your case you’ve used an `eq` matcher, an `any` matcher and two literals (`HttpMethd.GET` and `RestResponse.class`).

Comment: See also - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template. Spring’a built in call mocking facilities might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a matcher such as `Mockito.eq` or `Mockito.any` for one of the parameters in your stubbed or verified method call, you must use a matcher for ALL the parameters.  This is because of the way Mockito arranges its matchers in an internal stack.  So you should write

```
Mockito.when(this.restTlsTemplate
            .exchange(Mockito.eq(builder.toString()), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET), Mockito.any(), Mockito.eq(RestResponse.class))
            .getBody()).thenReturn(response());
```

where `Mockito.eq` has been placed around each parameter that you want to match exactly.

Comment: getting null pointer exception on same line after made changes suggested by you. Please check why? @Dawood ibn Kareem

Comment: When you've only supplied two lines of your code, there could be loads of reasons for a null pointer exception.  I guess you've used a variable without assigning a value to it.

Comment: see @Dawood ibn Kareem, null pointer exception showing in above exchange line only not in other code.